# Not needed results

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch version 2.3.3.

I have a document indexed with `_id`: `506GBBO25953J`. And I want to get **only this one** document. The problem is that I also get 9 other not needed documents.

Query:
`{"query": {"term": {"_id": "506GBBO25953J"}}}`

Results:

```
grep "_id" /tmp/dump 
      "_id" : "506GBBO25953J",
      "_id" : "404DDCN87823H",
      "_id" : "182JNYT51862G",
      "_id" : "928NSDK72999J",
      "_id" : "880RFWM18773C",
      "_id" : "963WLQD56637O",
      "_id" : "042BRRR44674H",
      "_id" : "905SWQI56804W",
      "_id" : "776DUXN15235Y",
      "_id" : "723CJRP41700R",
```

Also I tried bool query for a field in `_source`, same result.

`{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"term": {"ID": "506GBBO25953J"}}]}}}`

Why is that? How to return only one document?

Comment: Your first query is correct, how are you sending your request(using curl or some client library)?

Comment: It's probably a GET vs POST issue. Please show how you're sending your query.